# My reputation graph on Math.SE shows me as having the wrong reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-graph

On Math.SE, as of right now, I have 279 rep. This is correctly reported on my profile page. However, *the rep graph* on [the new profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/126378/maroon) suggests that I currently have 319 rep (as per the mouse-over):

[image: Rep graph]

A while ago, I lost 80 rep points from some voting reversal -- apparently someone was engaging in voter fraud -- and something makes me suspect that this might be related, except the difference between the rep I actually have and the rep the graph reports is only 40 points.

Comment: My guess is that the graph is taking the data from a different source (i.e. not the live tables) so it would be fast, and that source is not synchronized in case of vote reversal events.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few things that the graph doesn't account for all that well - I am looking at making it more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user was removed, and with them any reputation gained, the calculations for the graph did not have data to account for the split between posts that such a user voted on that were deleted and those that were not.

The effect was that some votes got added twice for this calculation and not once.

We have now added accounting for these and are recalculating reputation for those effected.

---